# How to best handle varying actions for the same rule in bison?

Tags: parsing, bison

I have the following grammar (SSCCE):

```
%token  WORD
%%
program     : word  word
            ;

word        : WORD  // have to translate only for first word
            ;
```

The rule `word : WORD` should have the action, that the token semantic value for `WORD` is suitably "translated" to the semantic value for the left hand side, only if that is the first `word` in the rule `program: word word`.

What is the best practice to do this in bison?

I do not see how to do this with actions.  I have to expand the grammar itself, to this:

```
%token  WORD
%%
program     : word_translated   word_not_translated
            ;

word_translated     : WORD  { // translate }
            ;

word_not_translated  : WORD { // do not translate }
            ;
```

OK, but this I do not like.  Because, the grammar has two symbols `word_translated` and `word_not_translated` which are exactly the same, as far as the grammar is concerned, so the grammar is too complicated and should be simplified to have one `word`.  The only reason for the added complexity, is so that the actions can be different.

Is this the only way to do this, and is this the best practice in bison to handle a situation like that?

Comment: Yes, this is the best practice -- when you need to do different actions for the same symbol (terminal or non-terminal) in different contexts, you just create a new singleton rule.

Comment: @Chris OK thank you, but in the meantime, I figured out how to do this:  use `$0`

Comment: @ChrisDodd Well I found out for the full-scale situation, not the simple SSCCE I have in my post, using `$0`, `$-1` and so forth, is impractical.  It is really like constructing the tree yourself and walking it.  So your comment is golden.  You should make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic actions are best performed from parse trees in any compiler or interpreter. If you are trying to perform linguistic semantic actions direction from bison rule actions you will always get into the kind of mess you have described.

Just build a parse tree in the bison action and then walk  the tree taking the appropriate semantic action once the full tree is known. Most standard compiler texts have working examples.

Comment: Thank you!  But I don't understand this.  I think I know what a "parse tree" is, and, according to the bison manual and yacc/bison texts, the parse tree is what bison builds, it is not for me to build it in a bison action, as you seem to suggest. The bison actions, are to react to the parse tree that is being built by bison.  In my case, the two WORD tokens are exactly the same as far as lexer is concerned - they cannot be distinguished by the lexer.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Other parser generators do have facilities for building trees but bison/yacc does not. It has to be manually coded. I have an instructional video for my students [here](https://youtu.be/oOFfVZrvhMA?list=PL3czsVugafjNLmIHA8ODBxuwWy8W4Uk9h)

Comment: Thank you! I watched your video and read more carefully the bison docs - indeed, I was wrong, bison doesn't build the tree.  In the video, it shows how to build the parse tree, it is a video for students, great, but for me, it is clear, no need to explain.  The question for me, is "why" I would need a parse tree.  I see that it may be needed in other applications to build and walk the tree, and I see that in my case I could do that to solve my problem. But in my case, it would be an overkill, even more complex than in my post.  I don't need a tree in my application. See below.

Comment: because your answer was helpful in making me read up on the subject, I will vote it up as "useful".

Comment: I beg your pardon Brian, after some more study, I found out I do need to generate a parse tree, cannot be without that.

Answer (score -1):

I will respectfully disagree with Brian's assertion that, bison actions should be used solely to build a parse tree, and then after parsing, the tree should be walked and during that, the real actions should be taken.  Or else, one "always gets into the kind of mess".

If that were so, the classic O'Reilly yacc text would not say: "Often the action code builds a parse tree corresponding to the
input, so that later code can process a whole statement or even a whole
program at a time".  Instead of "often" it would say something like "always".

However, Brian's answer was very useful in that, while trying to understand it, I had to read up.  And then I found out IMHO the right answer to my question, as it is posted.  I will post the answer for the benefit of future browsers.

IMHO the correct way is to use `$0`.  With the original grammar in my post, the pseudocode for the action would be:

```
if ($0 is meaningful)
    $$ = $1
else
    $$ = translate($1)
```

Comment: The bison manual states, with respect to the use of `$0$`: "This is a very risky practice, and to use it reliably you must be certain of the context in which the rule is applied." It is not at all clear how you propose to verify that "$0 is meaningful" without somehow venturing into undefined behaviour. It may work for you in a particular application on a particular architecture, etc., but it is not a technique that should be used without a clear understanding of its limitations.

Comment: @rici I am not arguing with the "risky" part.  But I disagree with "it is not clear how you propose to verify meaningful".  Very simple.  Look at my SSCCE. The application code can initialize `yylval` to an invalid value, or it can be declared `static` and have known initialization with zero bits.   `translate` function returns a valid non-zero value.  This is straightforward, isn't it?

Comment: that only works once. Yes, in your trivial grammar it is possible, but if `program` were not the top-level non-terminal, you would have rather less control over what value `yylval` had. And it is hardly worth using bison for a grammar so trivial, so I assume you actually have something a little more complicated in mind, as would anyone who stumbles upon this question. What you do in your code is absolutely your concern, and I have no intention of attempting to dissuade you. My comment and downvote are an attempt to attach a health warning for other readers.

Comment: @rici Good, I appreciate the discussion with you.  In fact, I did find out, after posting my answer, that just as you say, my "real" situation is not so simple and using `$0` is pretty much pointless, and I am now using a (kind of a) parse tree.  Thank you for all your help and critique.